# Bad SQL grammer jdbcTemplate spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am getting a bad SQL grammer error when trying to run this.

```
    public List<UserTemp> findByID(Integer PatientNumber) {
    String sql = "SELECT PatientNumber,FirstName,Surname from paitents WHERE 'PatientNumber' = ?,PatientNumber";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
            (rs, rowNum) ->
                    new UserTemp(
                            rs.getInt("PatientNumber"),
                            rs.getString("FirstName"),
                            rs.getString("Surname")
                    ));
}
```

I am trying to select a patient based on the PatientNumber

Answer (score 0):

Is your table called **paitents** or **patients**?